# Android: possible code to start a service when device goes to sleep and wakes from sleep

Tags: android, android-intent

I want my service to start automatically when the device goes to sleep and also when it wakes up. How do i do it without making the service run continuously in background to check the state of device?

For example, can i add my service to the list of system default services that get started up when a device wakes up?if so, how to do it?

Comment: Since your service will not be running when the device goes to sleep (by definition), you might consider editing your question to explain what you are *really* trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about phone events then broadcast receivers is the solution